# No parameterless constructor defined for this object in asp.netcore migrations

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, entity-framework-migrations, asp.net-core-mvc-2.0

I am new to ASP.NET Core. learning new version of .NET Core 2.0 using VS Code. I got stuck while doing creating database using migration. First, it gives an exception of implementation of IDesignTimeDbContextFactory. After solving this, it still gives an exception of

> No parameterless constructor defined for this object

Here's my code for DbContextClass:

```
public VegaDbContext CreateDbContext(string[] args)
{
    IConfigurationRoot configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
        .Build();
    var builder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<VegaDbContext>();
    var connectionString = 
    configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
    builder.UseSqlServer(connectionString);
    return new VegaDbContext(builder.Options);
}
```

Comment: check this way https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48758249/ef-core-migration-cant-use-secret-manager

Comment: Error message is pretty clean: Your models must have a parameterless constructor. Also don't read the config file every single time, it will create issues. https://stackoverflow.com/a/45876217/455493 on how to create a more abstract config reader or simply just use the DI and AddDbContext

Comment: @Tseng my model already have parameterless constructor. On other hand configuration file is not creating issue. I already try what ever all of you people are suggesting but i don't understand where problem is.

Comment: This problem is discussed here: https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/9467

Answer (score 1):

I had tried a couple of ways when I was experimenting with ef core. I faced similar issues too. Finally I found services working great. First you will need to create your `DBContext` with the following override constructor:

```
public VegaDbContext(DbContextOptions<VegaDbContext> options) : base(options)
{
}
```

In your start up, you can add your context as a service like this:

```
services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDBContext>(config => {
    config.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));
});
```

You can read in full detail about how dependency injection works here: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection

This part should help you with the migration. You can perform your migrations using the `dotnet ef` commands https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/cli/dotnet.

When using your db context, do ensure that you are using dependency injection so you make full use of the `AddDbContext` function and keep it DRY.

Answer (score 0):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/intro

If I were your in your shoes, I look at this document.

Here is the simple DbContext that you can find on this webSite

```
namespace ContosoUniversity.Data
{
    public class SchoolContext : DbContext
    {
        public SchoolContext(DbContextOptions<SchoolContext> options) : base(options)
        {
        }

        public DbSet<Course> Courses { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Enrollment> Enrollments { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Student> Students { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<Course>().ToTable("Course");
            modelBuilder.Entity<Enrollment>().ToTable("Enrollment");
            modelBuilder.Entity<Student>().ToTable("Student");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just got the same error. If you are careful the error description is actually giving you the solution of the problem.
  DesignTimeFactoryObject's constructor function should not take parameters.

```
public class ExampleDesignTimeFactory : IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<YourDBContext>{
public ExampleDesignTimeFactory(){ no constructor or no parameter constructor }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I use ASP.NET CORE 3.1 to create the project and it solved